# "A small question" versus "a little question"

Tags: word-choice, adjectives

Which adjective should I use with *question*, *small* or *little*?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[This question](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/31216/40336) is related.

Elaborating (though I don't think that any more needs to be said), both **small** and **little** are fine to say.

The sentence is not using **small** or **little** as quantifiers, but rather to denote the size.

However, it is perhaps worth noting that **little question** is [more popular](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=small+question%2C+little+question&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=).

Comment: That apparently massive preference for *little question* over ***small** question* intrigued me, since my natural inclination would be the other way. So I checked [**one** little/small question](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=one+small+question%2Cone+little+question&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=), which suggests that *small* has gradually been gaining traction over the past century, and may even be ahead now. [It wins in a Googlefight.](http://www.googlefight.com/index.php?lang=en_GB&word1=%22one+small+question%22&word2=%22one+little+question%22)

Comment: _Small_ sounds more natural to me too

Comment: Nice tool @FumbleFingers! I checked it for ["a" instead of "one"](http://www.googlefight.com/index.php?lang=en_GB&word1=%22a+small+question%22&word2=%22a+little+question%22) and it's the other way round... People do seem to use both interchangeably. If we extend the NGram, we get [this](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a+small+question%2Ca+little+question%2Cone+small+question%2Cone+little+question&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=).

Comment: Strange. If we look at [just the words **little** and **small**](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=little%2Csmall&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) it seems **little** was twice as common a century ago in written contexts, but they're now pretty much equal. Given that *small* has significantly increased in relative prevalence overall, I'd tend to expect that trend to be even more marked in casual (more "flexible") contexts. And that's confirmed by the fact that on Google Internet *small* now beats *little* by a factor of 3:2.

Comment: ...in short, even if we find apparent evidence that "*little question* is more popular" as of now, the smart money would be on that no longer being true at some point in the near future. So if a young person is learning usage *today*, they'd be better going for what looks like it'll be the dominant form tomorrow, not yesterday.

Comment: And it will probably fluctuate indefinitely as the language evolves. Who knows, we could get other words replacing those two after a few centuries.

Comment: Yes, the past isn't necessarily a guide to the future. But *small* has more going for it, I think. It's a bit irrelevant that it has one less letter, but surely the fact that it's got 50% less *syllables* would make it more attractive to lazy speakers (i.e. - most of us, most of the time). I personally normally enunciate *little* with a glottal stop, partly because I find the **/t -> /l** transition a little awkward. Score +1 to *little*, 'cos I couldn't say *small awkward* there. But +10 to *small* because I personally would virtually never want to use the comparative ***littler***.

Comment: Oh no, not littler! But yes, I do pronounce 'little' more as _litl_ almost to _lil_.

Comment: Interesting discussion. I'd say that in the expression "I have one [little] question for you"--an informal phrase, spoken in the first person--"little" is much more widely used. In a more formal context--say, a research journal article in the third person--a phrase like "one [small] question remains to be answered" is much more likely to use "small." To me this is the same as the more formal "small children" vs. less formal "little kids."